# bodyParser does not convert to text/xml type

Tags: xml, express, axios, body-parser

I'm trying to send a post xml request, but the body of the request is empty. using bodyParser I managed to transform the content type. But the backend expects a content-type: "text/xml" and in my request content-type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", even passing content-type: "text/xml".
It's giving error 415.

How to send the body of the request with the text/xml type?

my bodyParser declaration:

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: "text/xml" }));
```

Comment: Please share the code that creates the POST request. Is it Javascript code, or just an HTML form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping in mind that the `text` body parser will parse your request as **plain text** and not as XML, so you will need to do XML parsing as a separate step.

To set the content type of the request using axios:

```
const xml = "<example><childNode /></example>";
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/example',
    headers: { 
        'content-type': 'text/xml' 
    },
    data: xml,
});
```

---

Here is an end-to-end example:

```js
const express = require('express');
const { DOMParser } = require('@xmldom/xmldom');

const app = express();
const port = 4000;

app.use(express.text({ type: 'text/xml' }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.27.2/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const xml = "<example><childNode /></example>";
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/example',
            headers: { 
                'content-type': 'text/xml' 
            },
            data: xml,
        }).then(response => {
            const { childNodes } = response.data;
            alert(childNodes);
        });
    </script>
  `);
});

app.post('/example', (req, res) => {
    console.log('XML Body Source:', req.body);
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(req.body, 'text/xml');
    const childNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName('childNode');
    res.send({ childNodes: childNodes.length });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: what worked for me was adding a middleware to the axios request and change the Content-Type in the header while the request is performed. Ex:
```
(req, res, next) => {
    req.configAxios = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/xml",
      },
    };
}